# How to get the right output from this SELECT query?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query like so:

```
SELECT * FROM `purchases` p 
JOIN `purchase_types` pt ON p.purchase_type = pt.node
```

When I run it in PHPmyAdmin it returns the proper result set like so:

```
node | purchase_type | amount_spent | node | name
--------------------------------------------------
2    | 5             | 8.5000       | 5    | Lunch
3    | 5             | 1.5000       | 5    | Lunch
4    | 6             | 4.6600       | 6    | Dinner
```

This is my PHP code:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `purchases` p 
        JOIN `purchase_types` pt ON p.purchase_type = pt.node";

$query = mysql_query($sql);
$result = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);

$purchases = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $purchases[] = array(
        'name' => $row['name'],
        'amount_spent' => $row['amount_spent']
    );
}
```

for eaching over `$expenses` returns the following output:

```
3    | 5             | 1.5000       | 5    | Lunch
4    | 6             | 4.6600       | 6    | Dinner
```

What happens to the first "Lunch"? How can I have the PHP output be the same as the direct MySQL query output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You call `mysql_fetch_accoc` before `while`.  Don't.

---

You should also realize that `ext/mysql` will be deprecated and upgrade your code to use properly parameterized queries with PDO or mysqli

Answer (score 0):

try with mysql_fetch_array,

```
$purchases = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    $purchases[] = $row;
}
```

if you want to get data just do

```
foreach($purchases as $key => $value)
{
    $name = $value['name'];
    $amount_spent = $value['amount_spent'];

    echo 'name : '.$name.' , amount spent '.$amount_spent.'<br />';
}
```